# TypeError: .push is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have created a redux datastore where I want to basically store the index of pets which where liked by a user or disliked by a user. I am facing an issue where I am getting error where TypeError: .push is undefined. I am following a  basic redux tutorial mentioned here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcC8KZ_Ga2M
I am confused by the fact that I array is first defined and then undefined as I push integer in the array.

ProfileApp.js

```
class ProfileApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
   .........(Truncated for brevity)
   .........(Truncated for brevity)
   }
   componentWillMount() {

   .........(Truncated for brevity)
   this.props.likePets(this.state.currentIndex);
   .........(Truncated for brevity)
   this.props.dislikePets(this.state.currentIndex);



   }
   function mapStateToProps(state){
     return {
       likedPets: state.likedPets,
       dislikedPets: state.dislikedPets
     }
   }
   function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
     return{
       likePets: (i)=> dispatch({type:'LIKE_PETS'}),
       dislikePets: (i)=> dispatch({type:'DISLIKE_PETS'})
     }

   }
   export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProfileApp)
```

App.js

```
import  ProfileApp  from './src/ProfileApp';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';/
const initialState = {
  likedPets: [],
  dislikedPets: []

}
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{

console.log(state.likedPets)
console.log(state.dislikedPets)

  switch (action.type){

    case 'LIKE_PETS':
    return{likedPets: likedPets.push(action.index)}
    case 'DISLIKE_PETS':
    return{dislikedPets:dislikedPets.push(action.index)}
  }
  return state

}

const store = createStore(reducer);
export default class App extends React.Component {



  render() {
    return (
    <Provider store = {store}>
      <ProfileApp></ProfileApp>
    </Provider>

    )
  }
}
```

output when I first compile this code on console is as follows:
during initial load:

```
Array []
Array []
Running application "main" with appParams:.....(Trimed)
```

Useraction: Like a pet

```
Array []
Array []
```

Useraction: like  other pet

```
1
undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in your mapDispatchToProps in connect:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProfileApp)
```

to

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfileApp)
```

You need to spread your state in the reducer:

```
return{likedPets: likedPets.push(action.index)}
```

to

```
return{...state, likedPets: likedPets.push(action.index)}
```

otherwise you are overwriting the state in the store with an object that doesn't have your dislikedPets on it.

Also the push method of arrays returns the length of the array. Replace that with

```
likedPets: [...state.likedPets,action.index]
```

To get an array that is the current state (likedPets) with action.index added onto it.